A murder hidden amidst serial killing
I'm trying to recall a crime story made (and probably set) in the 20th century, where there's a serial killer with several victims. Our perceptive protagonist figures out that one of the crimes is subtly different. A previously-unsuspicious character did it, trying to foist it on the first killer.
Unfortunately I don't remember any specific details. Or more precisely, I'm sure I remember some of them, but they're blurred together with my memories of other mysteries & thrillers. Could be anything from film noir to a cop show.
Update: It had more plot than one could reasonably fit into an hour, so probably a movie, but possibly a series with continuity. And I think it was a whodunit, with internally consistent clues.
I saw it in the 1990s, on video, not in a theater.

I'm pretty sure that just about every Cop Drama, NCIS, CSI, Castle... etc... has had an episode with this theme. Do you have any other info at all? Even some sort of exclusionary info like "I know it's not ____" Is it in English? Any idea if it's set in a real city? Do you have a strong feeling about it being a movie or a TV show?

Maybe Red Riding: In the Year of Our Lord 1980, (2009).

With a serial killer claiming victim 13 and rumors of corruption in
  their force, the West Yorkshire cops are told to cooperate with a team
  from outside - Peter Hunter and two hand-picked associates. Hunter
  gets little help but plunges ahead, discovering that one of the 13
  victims may have a different killer. This part of the investigation
  leads to late-night calls, another murder, and bureaucratic moves to
  push Hunter aside: he may be getting close, not to the serial killer
  but to bad apples in the force.


Not the one, but thanks, it looks interesting. http://www.canistream.it/tv/series/85387/red-riding

This could be The Alphabet Murders, a Hercule Poirot story based on a novel by Agatha Christie. A second version as part of a serial show "Agatha Christie's Poirot" exists.
Four murders were committed. The names of the people killed had the initials A.A., B.B., C.C. and D.D. A suspect is found but in the process of the story it is revealed that three of the murders were just committed to distract from the fourth.
I don't remember exactly yet if all of the murders were committed by the real offender, how he exploited the suspect, or if he forced the other person to commit them. But obviously the other murders weren't coincidental, the idea of the offender was to draw attention to the initials so the police would investigate in that direction and not the background of each victim; it was about an heritage, if I remember correctly.
The movie is in black and white, from 1962. The second, serial version was aired 1992.

But isn't that the opposite of what the OP is asking for?

@Walt I don't remember the details; I think the three independent murders were committed by a mentally ill woman, maybe even not for distraction. I need to rewatch it, my phrasing in the answer probably was overconfident. I don't see that the OP explicitly demanded no connection between both so it doesn't look like the opposite but a variant to me.
